# Не работает увеличение картинки по клику

Tags: javascript, html

Есть отзывы `<div class="recall">` в них находится картинка, и клацая по ней, картинка должна увеличиться. Как это сделать при помощи `id` я знаю, но проблема усложняется тем, что в итоге отзывы должен добавлять человек далекий от `html`, и надо сделать универсальный способ, чтобы при нажатии на картинку появлялась увеличенная ее версия. Как я понял нужно получить значение src текущей картинки и подставить это значение в стиль или атрибут. ниже представлен код что в тоге вышло.

```
<main>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function showimg() {

                var getImageName = function() {
                    document.onclick = function(e) {
                        if (e.target.tagName == 'IMG') {
                            var curimg = toString(e.target.getAttribute("src"));
                        }
                    }
                }
                getImageName()

                document.getElementById('current-recall-img').style.backgroundImage = "url('" + curimg + "')";
                document.getElementById('current-recall-img').style.border = '1px solid red';
                document.getElementById('current-recall-img').style.width = '100px';
                document.getElementById('current-recall-img').style.height = '100px';

                var f = document.getElementById( bId );
                if ( f.style.display == 'none' ) { f.style.display = 'block'; }
                else { f.style.display = 'none'; }
            };
        </script>


        <div class="recall">
            <img alt="" class="img" src="img/img1.png" onclick="showimg( bId='recall-img')" />
            <div class="comment">Комментарий</div>
            <div class="date">25.05.16</div>
            <div class="master">Ирина</div>
            <div class="salon">Таганка</div>
        </div>

        <div class="recall">
            <img alt="" class="img" src="img/img2.png" onclick="showimg( bId='recall-img')" />
            <div class="comment">Комментарий</div>
            <div class="date">25.05.16</div>
            <div class="master">Ирина</div>
            <div class="salon">Таганка</div>
        </div>

        <div class="recall">
            <img alt="" class="img" src="img/img3.png" onclick="showimg( bId='recall-img')" />
            <div class="comment">Комментарий</div>
            <div class="date">25.05.16</div>
            <div class="master">Ирина</div>
            <div class="salon">Таганка</div>
        </div>

        <div class="shadow" id="recall-img" style="display: none;">
            <div id="current-recall-img" onclick="showimg( bId='recall-img' )" /></div>
        </div>
    </main>
```

Comment: "клацая по ней, картинка должна увеличиться" - цитируйте точнее: "Подъезжая к сией станцыи ..., у меня слетела шляпа."

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я все верно понял, результат должен быть примерно таким:

```js
var imageList = document.querySelectorAll('.recall > img');
var i = imageList.length;
while (i--) {
  imageList[i].addEventListener('click', showimg);
}


function showimg(e) {
  var imgSrc = null;
  if (e.target.tagName == 'IMG') {
    imgSrc = e.target.src
  }
  
  var preview = document.getElementById('preview');
  var currentImage = document.getElementById('current-recall-img');
  preview.style.display = 'block';
  currentImage.src = imgSrc;
};
```

```css
#current-recall-img img {
  width: 100%;
}

.recall img {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="recall">
    <img alt="" class="img" src="http://bart.com.ua/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/gradina-1333657576.jpg" />
    <div class="comment">Комментарий</div>
    <div class="date">25.05.16</div>
    <div class="master">Ирина</div>
    <div class="salon">Таганка</div>
  </div>

  <div class="recall">
    <img alt="" class="img" src="http://zonahelp.ru/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/44.jpg" />
    <div class="comment">Комментарий</div>
    <div class="date">25.05.16</div>
    <div class="master">Ирина</div>
    <div class="salon">Таганка</div>
  </div>

  <div class="recall">
    <img alt="" class="img" src="http://bart.com.ua/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/gradina-1333657576.jpg" />
    <div class="comment">Комментарий</div>
    <div class="date">25.05.16</div>
    <div class="master">Ирина</div>
    <div class="salon">Таганка</div>
  </div>

  <div id="preview" style="position: absolute; right: 0;top:0; width: 400px; height: 400px;border: 1px solid red; display: none;">
    <img id="current-recall-img" />
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: Да, именно это мне и нужно. Спасибо огромное. А не мог бы ты мне пояснить, почему у меня не работало?

Comment: У вас там много недочетов, основным является переменная `curimg`, которая объявляется внутри функции, но никуда не возвращается, и не объявлена выше функции для переприсвоения